# How to enable Spatial configuration of QueryDSL in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, querydsl

I would like for QueryDSL to autoconvert spatial types as per [link](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.1/reference/html_single/#d0e1482). It says that to do that in Maven you simply need to enable the `spatial` configuration flag. How can I do that Gradle?

Comment: Can you perhaps provide your base Gradle build script in which you’d like to enable that configuration flag?

Comment: @Chriki Should it matter? Should it not be inserted the same way into the script, regardless of other content?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is add the querydsl-spatial to the `annotationProcessor` classpath in gradle, just under the standard `querydsl-apt` dependency, as follows:

```
    annotationProcessor "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${querydsl_version}:hibernate"
    annotationProcessor "com.querydsl:querydsl-spatial"
```